# How to capture event when ajax request is called?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I've developed my application in Yii2. I've used kartik ajax file upload. When we click upload button of Kartik it send ajax request, in that request it sends file to upload to server.

I want to capture an event before ajax request starts for a specific form.

This is php code:

```
use kartik\widgets\FileInput;
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'login-form','options' => [
    'class'=> "form-photo"
  ]]); ?>
<?php 
    echo $form->field($model, 'photo')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
        'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'uploadUrl' => Url::to(['/site/photo-upload']),
        ]
    ]);
?>
 <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

When we select file in this plugin and click on upload button it sends ajax request and i want to check what does server response for this request.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your relevant code.

Comment: I have post my code

Comment: What *event* are you looking to capture?

Comment: @Marcus I think he mean before ajax request runs he want to capture that event.

Comment: ^Granted. But a *click* event? A *mouse* event? A *touch* event? Etc. There are a lot of events, ie. `$().action(function(event) { event.what? });`

Comment: @Marcus That event when ajax request is called. I want to confirm is there really event when ajax request calls

Comment: `beforeSend`? `complete`? `success`? All events. OP has yet to state what event is of concern.

Answer (score 0):

Add an onclick handler for the button. Since you're using a framework and haven't posted your frontend code I can't tell you how to select the button you're targeting.

```
// remove default behavior
$(button).off("click");
$(button).click(function(e){
    // prevent form from submitting
    e.preventDefault();

    // do stuff

    // perform ajax
    $.ajax({
    url: /*add your target file here */,
    type: 'post',
    data: { 
            /* add your json object here */
            },
    success: function(data, status) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);

    }, error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
    }, complete: function(){    
    }
}); // end ajax call
});
```

Comment: But he mean before ajax request runs he want to capture that event.

Comment: I think I've addressed that now.

Comment: Kartik plugin send requests by itself he wants to capture that request.